# running ssh command from a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I am new to shell scripting , I am trying to run the following command from shell script .

```
 diff <(ssh user@remote_host 'cat remote_file.txt') <(ssh user2@remote_host2 'cat remote_file2.txt')
```

but getting an error :

```
./a.sh: syntax error at line 1: `(' unexpected
```

I tried some example trough googleing which says to use $() around the code , but it did not work can any one please help me with this .

Comment: Sounds like you are using `/bin/sh` for your script which doesn't support Process Substitution. Try using `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Hi  Etan , I tried with both `#!/bin.sh` and `#!/bin/bash` in both case i get an error  
`./a.sh: syntax error at line 2: `vars=$' unexpected``

Comment: How are you running the script? Does it have execute permissions? That snippet only has one line. If you get errors from line 2 we can't possibly help you with those (and an error on line 2 means that `bash` accepted the `<()` syntax).

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to use the output from the two remote files in a 'diff'. There are many things wrong in your solution:

- You cannot redirect two output streams into one input stream
- diff only works on files, not on stdin
- using the output from one command as the input for another command is done using a pipe. Redirects are either from file to command or from command to file.
- parenthesis are used to bundle commands, for instance "( echo a ; echo b ) | cat" will cause the output of 'echo a' and 'echo 'b' to be passed in one stream to the input of 'cat', which will simply print it.

What I would do (to accomplish what I think you want to do) is turn it into three seperate commands:

```
ssh user@remote_host 'cat remote_file.txt' > file1
ssh user2@remote_host2 'cat remote_file.txt' > file2
diff file1 file2
```

Comment: Hi All , 
I created a shell script with the following idea as presented , which is as follows :
<pre> 
`
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
srchost=`echo $1 | cut -d ':' -f 1`
srcpath=`echo $1 | cut -d ':' -f 2`
dishost=`echo $2 | cut -d ':' -f 1`
dispath=`echo $2 | cut -d ':' -f 2`
echo $srchost
echo $srcpath
echo $dispath
echo $dishost
ssh $srchost `cat $srcpath` > file1
ssh $dishost `cat $dispath` > file2
diff file1 file2
`
</pre>

** this scripting getting stuck **

Comment: `<()` is not input redirection. It is Process Substitution and using that twice on a single command line is perfectly fine. This makes all four of the points in this post incorrect (as applied here).

Comment: Using files for this is a perfectly reasonable answer but not because anything was wrong with the concept in the OP and, of course, has the cost of writing to and reading from disk twice (likely cached but still).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. And I thought I was an expert in this area. :P

Answer (score 0):

I just make  this bash script without problems

```
#!/bin/bash
diff <(ssh user@remote_host cat remote_file.txt) <(ssh user2@remote_host2 cat remote_file2.txt)
exit 0
```

this work with the next conditions:
-remote_host and remote_host2 stay in the list of `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
-user and user2 exists and have permissions
-remote_host and remote_host2  are operative and have ssh server on
-user@remote_host and user2@remote_host2 have configured ssh for work without passwords
if you not know how do this see http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

maybe your error stay in `'`  but it must work well if you don't use `'remote_file.txt'` and only use `remote_file.txt`